# Count of element in database ajax,json in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, json

How can I take count of element in my database with ajax/json in asp.net? With GET method? So far I've got this:

```
// GET: /People/
public JsonResult Index()
        {
            var count = db.People.ToList().Count;
            return Json(count);
        }
```

in javascript:

```
   function check_count() {
     var how_many=$.ajax(
          {
              type:'GET',
              url:'/People/',
              success: function(data){
                  alert('successful');
              }

          });

          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have looks OK, except for one little thing:

```
var how_many = $.ajax({
    // ...
});
```

The AJAX call returns a "promise", it lets you chain things together, handle errors etc.

The reason for this is that AJAX calls are async, you start them and they (hopefully) will finish some time in the future. The line with your `alert('successful');` is the code that will be run once the call is finished.

Change that code to handle your data, perhaps try the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/People/',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        // this is like a break point, so you can inspect things
        debugger;
    }
});
```

As long as you have debugging enabled in your browser you'll be able to check what data was returned and work out what code you want from there.